# didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView not called

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I've implemented three methods of `GMSMapViewDelegate`, of which two (`markerInfoWindow`, `willMove`) are getting called as expected while `didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView` is never triggered when I click the 'My Location' button.

Initialization:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY")
        mapView = GMSMapView(frame: view.frame)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        view.insertSubview(mapView, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Delegate implementation:

```
extension MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        ...
        return infoView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        ...
    }

    func didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView(mapView: GMSMapView!) -> Bool {
        ...
        return false
    }
}
```

I tried to:

- Initialize in `viewDidLoad`.
- Change the order of the methods in `viewDidAppear` (for example, setting the delegate after inserting the view).
- Set the class in storyboard to be `GMSMapView` rather than adding in programmatically.

But nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found the solution ? I am working on objective-c proect , below suggested solution didnt work at all

Comment: @Anita you need to have isMyLocationEnabled set to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing _

```
func didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView!) -> Bool {
    ...
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Eventually the current signature is `func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {

    return false //default move map to my location
}
```